# How can I attach another scene object to my animated, imported collada mesh?

Tags: three.js

I have the following animation set up using Three.js:

http://frontier.lincoln.ac.uk/3d/development/Stage2/characters/man2.html

Please ignore the ropey weighted mesh, it is a quick re-mock up.  The real deal can be found here ( http://frontier.lincoln.ac.uk/3d/development/Stage2/characters/man.html )

Here's the problem.  See his red hat? (in the first URL).  That should be on his head.  So, I have created a dummy object (the tiny green cube on top of the characters head).  This is not part of the skin of the character and can be addressed as a child object of the skin.

However, as the character mesh is at the mercy of the animation (morphTargetInfulences etc. - I haven't quite figured out how it all works yet) how do I get the hat to be placed where the dummy object is and have it move with it?

Here is the business end of the code but feel free to route around the source of the above file:

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var particleLight, pointLight;
        var dae, skin, skin2, headgear, test2;

        var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load('../../../models/test_models/hat.js', function colladaReady( geometry ) {
            headgear = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, faceMaterial);
            loadMan();
        });

        function loadMan(){

            var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
            loader.load( '../../../models/test_models/test4.DAE', function colladaReady( collada ) {
                dae = collada.scene;
                skin = collada.skins[0];
                //this is the reference to the dummy object
                skin2 = collada.skins[0].children[0];
                dae.getChildByName( "node-CATRigHub001", true ).scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
                dae.position.y = -2
                dae.scale.x = dae.scale.y = dae.scale.z = 0.1;
                dae.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
                //here is where i've added to the hat to the dummy object
                skin2.add(headgear);
                dae.updateMatrix();

                init();
                animate();
            } );

        }

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.set( 2, 2, 3 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            scene.add( dae );

            particleLight = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 4, 8, 8 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xcccccc } ) );
            scene.add( particleLight );

            // Lights

            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc ) );

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(/*Math.random() * 0xffffff*/0xcccccc );
            directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
            directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
            directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
            directionalLight.position.normalize();
            scene.add( directionalLight );

            pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xcccccc, 3 );
            pointLight.position = particleLight.position;
            scene.add( pointLight );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            //renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

        }

        var t = 0;
        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            if ( t > 24 ) t = 0;
            if ( skin ) {
                for ( var i = 0; i < skin.morphTargetInfluences.length; i++ ) {
                    skin.morphTargetInfluences[ i ] = 0;
                    skin2.morphTargetInfluences[ i ] = 0;
                }

                skin.morphTargetInfluences[ Math.floor( t ) ] = 1;
                skin2.morphTargetInfluences[ Math.floor( t ) ] = 1;

                t += 0.5;

            }

            render();
            stats.update();

        }

        function render() {

            var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;

            camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 10;
            camera.position.y = 2;
            camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 10;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            particleLight.position.x = Math.sin( timer * 4 ) * 3009;
            particleLight.position.y = Math.cos( timer * 5 ) * 4000;
            particleLight.position.z = Math.cos( timer * 4 ) * 3009;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like good old Quake MD2 models - every prop is also animated morph with animation frames synced to all animation frames of the base mesh (e.g. running_gun, idle_gun, running_hat, idle_hat).

See, for example, weapons here:

http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_morphtargets_md2.html

You would need to do this when exporting the model, having all props animated together with the base model and then export them one by one individually.

It wouldn't be very elegant or efficient but it should do the job and work straight-out-of-box (like MD2 models, which ultimately also end up as morphs, you just need to map your asset pipeline to MD2 pipeline).

Another option, as you mentioned Collada, could be to somehow use the original skeleton in addition to morphs (that is, if your model does have skeleton, I think Collada allows both skinning and morphing).

Though this I guess would require messing with ColladaLoader (morphs are baked by software skinning, so information about bone frames is somewhere, there should be something like "head bone").

Or maybe you could somehow layer rigid body animation of props in addition to skinned / morphed base mesh into Collada, something like animated parts here:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_collada_keyframe.html

Comment: I am going with the MD2 "method" of animating the props using the same rig and then attaching them in Three. As this is just a proof of concept demo, i won't be tinkering with custom vertex shaders just yet :)  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just add the hat as part of the skin that you're animating.

Comment: That would certainly make things easier - BUT - the point is to work out a system where the user can define which type of hat they want to wear from a collection...

Comment: There must be some way to tap into the positional data of the dummy node...

P.s. congrats on the double mention of THREE.js in this months .net magazine!

Comment: Ah, that's tricky. Because only in the vertex shader you know where the hat is supposed to be... you may need to get dirty writing your custom vertex shader :S  Or maybe there could be a software based morphtargets implementation that can be done just for one vertex...

Comment: Ah, I didn't know .net magazine mentioned three.js. Cool :)

Comment: I think, for now while the demo is still proof of concept, I will stick with using an additional skeleton to animate the headgear as suggested by alteredq.

It isn't the most effcient but it will do.  Later on, I will investigate the custom vertex shader option as that is the optimised way. Thanks for reply.